# Emitting headers from a tiny Python web-framework

Tags: python, frameworks

I am writing a web-framework for Python, of which the goal is to be as "small" as possible (currently under 100 lines of code).. You can see the current code [on github](http://github.com/dbr/pyerweb/tree/master)

Basically it's written to be as simple to use as possible. An example "Hello World" like site:

```
from pyerweb import GET, runner

@GET("/")
def index():
    return "<strong>This</strong> would be the output HTML for the URL / "

@GET("/view/([0-9]+?)$")
def view_something(id):
    return "Viewing id %s" % (id) # URL /view/123 would output "Viewing id 123"

runner(url = "/", # url would be from a web server, in actual use
       output_helper = "html_tidy" # run returned HTML though "HTML tidy"
```

Basically you have a function that returns HTML, and the GET decorator maps this to a URL.

When `runner()` is called, each decorated function is checked, if the URL regex matches the request URL, the function is run, and the output is sent to the browser.

Now, the problem - outputting headers. Currently for development I've just put a line before the `runner()` call which does `print Content-type:text/html\n` - this is obviously a bit limiting..

My first ideas was to have the functions return a dict, something like..

```
@GET("/")
def index():
    return {
        "html": "<html><body>...</body></html>",
        "headers": {"Location":"http://google.com"}
    }
```

I really don't like this - having to return a dict with a specifically named key isn't nearly as nice as just returning a string..

I could check if the returned data is a dict, if so use `returned_data['html']` as the output, if it's a string, there is no custom headers to be sent... but this means to go from no headers (which would be the case a huge majority of the time) to headers, you'd have to change the return function from `return my_html` to `return {'html':my_html}` which isn't very elegant either..

After writing this, I discovered "Sinatra" - a similar-in-use Ruby library, and looked at how it dealt with headers:

```
get "/" do
    content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
end
```

This seems like it could be nice enough in Python:

```
@GET("/")
def index():
    header("location", "http://google.com")
```

To implement this, I was considering changing how the functions are executed - instead of simply using the return value, I would change `sys.stdout` to a StringIO, so you could do..

```
def index():
    print "<html>"
    print "<head><title>Something</title></head>"
    print "<body>...</body>"
    print "</html>
```

..without having to worry about concatenating a bunch of strings together. The upshot of this is I could have a separate stream for headers, so the above `header()` function would write to this.. Something like:

```
def header(name, value):
    pyerweb.header_stream.write("%s: %s" % (name, value))
```

Basically, the question is, how would you output headers from this web-framework (mostly in terms of *use*, but to a lesser extent implementation)?

Comment: question: what's the purpose of the project? Isn't webpy a tiny enough framework?

Comment: Nope. The goal is to be under 100 lines of code. It is basically an excuse to play around with decorators and other things in Python I haven't used much before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) for an excellent design pattern for a very lightweight web server.  If your server has this exact API, you can reuse it in a lot of context with a lot of other products.

PEP 333 (WSGI) suggests that you don't directly return the page, but you provide the HTML page to a "start_response" callable object, which wraps your HTML in the proper HTTP response, with the proper headers.

Answer (score 3):

you could use that idea of returning a dict or a string, but add a new decorator, so the 'evolution' for a user would be:

simple html:

```
@GET("/")
def index():
return "<html><body>...</body></html>"
```

with constant headers (one @HEADER for each one, or a dict with all of them):

```
@GET("/")
@HEADER("Location","http://google.com")
def index():
return "<html><body>...</body></html>"
```

with complex, maybe calculated headers:

```
@GET("/")
def index():
return {
    "html": "<html><body>...</body></html>",
    "headers": {"Location":"http://google.com"}
}
```

the @HEADER() decorator would simply change the returned value, so the 'framework' code would stay simple.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider the notion of returning [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html) - headers are part of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http).
If you build your framework around an HTTP stream, the headers are simply lines that precede the HTML payload.

A headers example from the above link:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Etag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 438
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

For a Python example, see the implementaion of [`BaseHTTPRequestHandler.send_header(keyword, value`)](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.send_header).

Comment: This framework isn't "designed around an HTTP stream", it's designed to be a nice to use as possible. Making the user manually print headers followed by two carriage-returns would be not-nice to use, and difficult to make send default-headers.. I see your point, but I want to abstract HTTP-stuff